# CodenameOne - Android permission error with android.buildToolsVersion=27

Tags: android, codenameone

I tried building my app with android.buildToolsVersion=27 .
The build and installation were successful, but in failed on startup  with:

> E/DatabaseUtils( 2346): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission
>   Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling
>   from user 0; this requires
>   android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL E/DatabaseUtils( 2346): 
>   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 2346):     at
>   android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 2346):     at
>   com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 2346):     at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 2346):     at
>   android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 2346):     at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388) E/DatabaseUtils(
>   2346):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
>   W/ActivityManager( 2346): Permission Denial: get/set setting for user
>   asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires
>   android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Also tried setting the android.targetSDKVersion to 27, 25 and 23 with the same result.

I've added this to android.xpermissions, with the same result:

```
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
```

Previously I've used android.buildToolsVersion=25 with no android.targetSDKVersion specified and everything worked. This setup still works, however I'd like migrate to the newer version.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: That permission is not mentioned on developer.android.com - is it something ancient that has been long deprecated and now is finally removed?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add that permission without an OEM signature. You are using API's which worked at the 4.x era such as leaving the user sandbox to open a database in an arbitrary location as read/write. -2 is essentially your app privileges whereas user 0 means the device owner privileges. You probably can't get those.

The answer is that google no longer allows you to do this. You could target older API levels but google won't accept you into the play store if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

The crash was not caused by this error, but by another one, due to the fact that, when building for api level 27, support for v4 is dropped, and I was using that to get the gcm token. I have documented everything here: [CodenameOne - Android app fails to start when building with android.buildToolsVersion=27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181747/codenameone-android-app-fails-to-start-when-building-with-android-buildtoolsve)