# CodenameOne - Android app fails to start when building with android.buildToolsVersion=27

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, codenameone

I'm using gcm and the app failed to start due to this error:

> AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.()' is inaccessible to
>   class 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' (declaration of
>   'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in
>   /data/app/net.segoia.opengroups.mobile-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)

This was caused by this line:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
```

The problem is that when building for api level 27, support for android v4 is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

What solved the problem is adding these two build hints:

```
android.supportV4=true
android.supportv4Dep=compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
```

This took a while to figure out, especially because the android.supportV4Dep is not even documented, and the android.supportV4 alone is not enough. I have learned about the android.supportV4Dep from another stackoverflow answer to a different question, so I thought I would document this here.